# Time-based triggers for google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I create Add-on for google spreadsheets. Is there a way to create a Trigger programmatically tied to the given spreadsheet. In the documentation I found a description of two classes `SpreadsheetTriggerBuilder` and `ClockTriggerBuilder`. But as far as I understand, I need something in between.

Comment: What does this "tying" do? Or what do you expect it to do?

Comment: Please provide more details on what you want to accomplish. Your question is very vague.

Comment: I want create single time-based trigger for document where used my addon. For multiple users

Answer (score 0):

You can create triggers in two ways:

- **manually**
- **programmatically**

However, since your main purpose is to create these triggers in an add-on, you should create them programmatically. Time-driven triggers are not tied to a particular spreadsheet, as they **trigger** the execution of a function.

So, creating a time-driven trigger should look something like this:

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('functionToDoSomething')
      .timeBased()
      .everyHours(1)
      .create();
}
```

The trigger above will *trigger* the execution of the `functionToDoSomething` function every hour.

Add-on triggers are also subject to restrictions, the most notable one being:

> An add-on can use a time-driven trigger once per hour at most.

You might also benefit from taking a look at this documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-triggers).

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable);
- [Triggers For Editor Add-Ons](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-triggers).